# Change saved iPhone Web app meta tag from black to black-translucent

Tags: ios, iphone, metadata, iphone-standalone-web-app

Problem: ios Web app which is saved to users home screen previously had the meta tag "apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" set to content="black". We just redesigned the app and would like to take advantage of the black-translucent statusbar, however since all the previous users saved the app to their home screen when content="black" was set it doesn't seem to update to "black-translucent" unless the user removes the app and re-downloads it.

Solution I'd like to avoid: Detect the viewport height and if it's the full height of the device then show the re-design style otherwise if its less than the full height don't show the updated style.

Is there any way to update the existing user's saved apps with the black-translucent status-bar style?